# Ruby: Match keys in a hash to return respective key+value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have hash which is

```
hash = {"stars"=>"in the galaxy", "fin"=>"is for fish", "fish"=>"has fins"}
```

Now I have a find method

```
def find(value)
    if hash.empty? == true
      return {}
    else
     return  hash
    end
  end
```

Now i want to do is- when executed `find("fi")` , I want the method to return all the hash key+ value which contain `fi` in the key. So an output such that would look like -

```
{"fin"=>"is for fish", "fish"=>"has fins"}
```

Please note "fi" is not fixed. It can be anything. Since Find method accepts an argument `value`.

Any help or suggestion is appreciate. I tried hash#select. but wasnt so helpful. I am not really sure what to use here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hash.select {|k, _| k.include? str}` where `str` is the string you're looking for.

Comment: buh.. i didnt know it looked for all matching cases. Thanks so much :).

Answer (score 6):

I'd use something like:

```
hash = {"stars"=>"in the galaxy", "fin"=>"is for fish", "fish"=>"has fins"}
pattern = 'fi'
hash.select{ |k,v| k[pattern] }
# => {"fin"=>"is for fish", "fish"=>"has fins"}
```

Comment: Didn't know you can use pattern right like that...
you can also add it like pattern = /fi/
or hash.select{|k,v| k[/pattern/]}